# Passing vars using reusable workflow with no success

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-reusable-workflows

We try to pass some env variables using a workaround to the reusable workflow as follows, but no variables are passed.

Workflow YAML is:

```yaml
name: "call my_reusable_workflow"

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

env: 
  env_branch: ${{ github.head_ref }}
  env_workspace: ${{ github.workspace }}

jobs:
  call_reusable_workflow_job:
    uses: my_github/my-reusable-workflow-repo/.github/workflows/used_wf_test.yml@master
    with:
      env_vars: |
        hello-to=Meir
        branch_name=${{ env.env_branch }}
    secrets:
      my_token: ${{secrets.ENVPAT}}
```

and the reusable workflow YAML is:

```yaml
name: my_reusable_workflow

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      env_vars:
        required: true
        type: string
        description: list of vars and values
    secrets:
      giraffe_token:
        required: true    

jobs:
  reusable_workflow_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:  
    - name: set environment variables
      if: ${{ inputs.env_vars }}
      run: |
        for env in "${{ inputs.env_vars }}"
        do
          printf "%s\n" $env >> $GITHUB_ENV
        done
```

When the action is running it gets the value of `hello-to=Meir` but doesn't get the value `branch_name=${{ env.env_branch }}`.

I tried to pass the value also as `branch_name=${{ github.head_ref }}` but with no success.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Limitations](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#limitations) of [Reusing workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows):

> Any environment variables set in an `env` context defined at the workflow level in the caller workflow are not propagated to the called workflow. For more information, see "[Variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables)" and "[Contexts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#env-context)."

So, the [`env` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#env-context) is not supported in reusable workflow callers at the moment.

---

However, you can pass the [Default Environment Variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables) to reusable workflow callers.

For example, in your particular scenario, you want to use these contexts:

- `github.head_ref`
- `github.workspace`

The equivalent default environment variables are:

- `GITHUB_HEAD_REF`
- `GITHUB_WORKSPACE`

And, your reusable workflow (e.g. `reusable_workflow_set_env_vars.yml`) will be called by its caller (e.g. `reusable_workflow_set_env_vars_caller.yml`) like this:

```yaml
name: reusable_workflow_set_env_vars_caller

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  set-env-vars:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reusable_workflow_set_env_vars.yml
    with:
      env_vars: |
        TEST_VAR='test var'
        GITHUB_HEAD_REF=$GITHUB_HEAD_REF
        GITHUB_WORKSPACE=$GITHUB_WORKSPACE
        GITHUB_REF=$GITHUB_REF
```

---

Apart from that, regarding your implementation of the reusable workflow (e.g. `reusable_workflow_set_env_vars.yml`):

- As the `env_vars` is of [`string` type](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_callinputsinput_idtype), you need to somehow solidify it against YAML multiline whitespace variants e.g. `>`.
- You can visualize and observe whitespace on this online utility (https://yaml-multiline.info/).
- With the current implementation, there may be word splitting for variable values containing spaces in them. So, you might need to iterate per line i.e. up to the newline character. This thread (https://superuser.com/questions/284187/bash-iterating-over-lines-in-a-variable) might be helpful for this.