# Replace env var in uses: block in GitHub Action

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to re-use a workflow in my GitHub repo and want to do something like this:

```yaml
name: deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'dev'
      - 'main'

jobs:
  run-other-workflow:
    uses: MyRepo/.github/workflows/some-other-workflow.yml@${{env.GITHUB_REF_NAME}}
```

I can't get this to work in any way that I am trying. Is this possible? Not being able to do this leads to duplicate templates.

EDIT:

Also tried:

```
jobs:
  run-other-workflow:
    uses: MyRepo/.github/workflows/some-other-workflow.yml@${{github.ref_name}}
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75150142/passing-vars-using-reusable-workflow-with-no-success

Comment: Try: `${{ github.ref_name }}` and see https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context for more details.

Comment: Unfortunately did not work: failed to fetch workflow: reference to workflow should be either a valid branch, tag, or commit

Comment: Please check https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context for other contexts that might be possible candidates for your use case. BTW, what is your intention in making this dynamic? Are you trying to append the current commit reference or something else?

Comment: If I am deploying from the dev branch I want the workflow file from the dev branch to be used. If I am deploying from the main branch, I want the workflow file from the main branch to be used. Normally you do @v1 or something, but that isn't too useful if you are defining the workflow yourself

Comment: Right. That makes sense. What if you don't mention anything? Shouldn't that pull the reusable workflow from the current branch?

Comment: I tried that first and it doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Was there any error? Do you remember why it didn't work?

Comment: Take a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75105072/how-to-separate-conditions-for-different-event-types-in-github-actions. Might be helpful too.

Comment: Thanks, it was. See my answer. Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The documentation uses the following example:

```yaml
uses: octo-org/example-repo/.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml@main
```

This implies that you need to reference an org and a repo. This also seems to lead to the requirement of adding `@main` or `@v1`.

However, you can also reference your repo without the org like so:

```yaml
uses: ./.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml
```

If you do it like this adding an `@ref` is not required. This was not immediately clear from the documentation.